Cannot find native module 'ExpoTaskManager' when using expo-background-fetch in React Native
When using the expo-task-manager package in my React Native project, I encounter the following error when trying to import the TaskManager and BackgroundFetch modules:
Error: Cannot find native module 'ExpoTaskManager'

Additional Information:

React Native version: 0.73.6

Expo version: 50.0.14

Platform: Android


I have tried removing then android folder and rebuild it but nothing changed.
I am not using expo-go
